# How to make screenshots with device bezels for the App Store in Xcode?

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

How can I make these kind of pictures?

(Picture 1)

[image: Screenshot of app with device bezel]

I know you can just take a screenshot, but it looks different:

[image]

Even if I don't take the screenshot with iPhone 12 but instead the iPhone SE, it doesn't look like in Picture 1 (unfortunately the iPhone 10 doesn't work because it doesn't suggest for iOS 14.3).

**Does anyone have an idea how I can take such a picture?**

Comment: I use appscreen.studio to make screenshots with different bezels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@ivanmoskalev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737347/ivanmoskalev) said, you need to edit the image yourself (Xcode does not have this functionality built-in). You can look for mockup frames on the internet, but I prefer this app called [Rotato](https://www.rotato.xyz/).

[image]

It's $50 to remove the watermark. But you also get animations and lots of devices. In my opinion, completely worth it.

Comment: Do you know how Rotato behaves with commercial purpose?

Comment: @user14850460 Yep, it [says](https://www.rotato.xyz/terms) "You can use videos and images produced and exported from Rotato in any of your awesome works, commercially or not"

Comment: Do you have a Link for That? That would be awesome.

Comment: @user14850460 https://www.rotato.xyz/terms, then scroll down to "License" -> "Exports from Rotato"

Answer (score 2):

The realistic device bezel is added later via image manipulation. There is a number of services and scripts that do it.

I personally prefer using templates from Figma Community, there are quite a lot of them:

- https://www.figma.com/community/file/891325178364097650
- [more device mockups](https://www.figma.com/community/search?model_type=hub_files&q=iphone%20mockups)
- [more App Store screenshot templates](https://www.figma.com/community/search?model_type=hub_files&q=app%20store)

Just don't forget to check licensing – whether the template author allows you to use derived images commercially.

Disclaimer: I didn't check for that in the links I posted above, nor do I recommend any particular template.